# Is there a way to enable fuzzy Bash auto-completion like Intellij has?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting, bashrc, .bash-profile

I use Intellij a lot, and one of the features I love is the auto-completion. Notice how you can skip letters in your input and it guesses what you want based on those letters:

[image]

Is there a way to enable this kind of auto-completion in Bash? I have [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) enabled but it only works for typing in the **prefix** of what you not, not with incomplete input such as in the image.

Comment: https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion